# Different column size for a listview in Xamarin

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, xamarin

I have a listview and each row is shown after inflating the following view. It is a LinearLayout and it works fine until I give each textview (which is a column in my list) the same size. If I change any of those width I get unexpected results. For example, if I put 0.5 to the first textView (called "test") I was expecting that textView to have much smaller size, but it is opposite. So I tried using 3, but again very unexpected behavior. So if I want the first textView to be much smaller than the other 4, how can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp">
 <TextView
    android:text="Test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:id="@+id/testView" />
<TextView
    android:text="Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:id="@+id/nameView" />
<TextView
    android:text="Surname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:id="@+id/surnameView" />
<TextView
    android:text="Age"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:id="@+id/ageView" />
<TextView
    android:text="Profession"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:id="@+id/professionView" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I change any of those width I get unexpected results.

The reason you get unexpected results is that you set every `TextView` `layout_width` property to `match_parent`. The [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) said that :

> Child views can specify a weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight.

We can see that the `layout_widt` property for every `TextView` in your layout should set to `wrap_content`. It means the width of the `TextView` equal to the original width (`android: layout_width =warp_content`) plus the proportion of the remaining space. Just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoI1U.png).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Just a little bit confused so please apologise me for asking more. My goal is to make the first textView (named "Test") much smaller than the other 4 textViews. Let's say the content of the first textView is just * or empty, so 1 character at most. I want the other 4 textViews to fill the remaining space equally. Should I use android:layout_height="wrap_content" for the first and android:layout_weight="1" for the others?

Comment: Yes, just delete the android:layout_weight property in the first TextView.

Comment: I hope this works but I can only check tonight. I will come back to you with a feedback on the answer if you don't mind. But thanks again for the help.

Comment: I removed the android:layout_weight property from the first TextView but the results was still wrong, with the first TextView is now filling all the space. Then I realized I had to change also the android:layout_width property from "match_parent" to "wrap_content". It works now, thanks a lot.